# Filter two Dateframes because of the Distance

Tags: python

I got a smaller Dataframe ~300 rows and a bigger one ~100000 rows, each of those dataframes has x-and y-koordinates in it. Know I want to only get those rows from the second dataframe which are in a relative close distance to any of the koordinates of my first dataframe. Unfortunately I can't use geopy or any source of package except pandas.

I was able to calculate distance with haversine to get a distance, but it takes ages to use haversine on each distance, check if it is in range or to big and than go on.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, atan2

# Function to calculate the Haversine distance between two points
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    R = 6371  # Radius of the Earth in kilometers

    # Convert latitude and longitude to radians
    lat1_rad = radians(lat1)
    lon1_rad = radians(lon1)
    lat2_rad = radians(lat2)
    lon2_rad = radians(lon2)

    # Haversine formula
    dlat = lat2_rad - lat1_rad
    dlon = lon2_rad - lon1_rad
    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1_rad) * cos(lat2_rad) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c

    return distance

# Distance threshold in meters
distance_threshold = 100

# Filter dataframe 2 based on proximity to dataframe 1
filtered_rows = []
for _, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    distances = np.array([haversine(row2['x'], row2['y'], row1['x'], row1['y']) for _, row1 in df1.iterrows()])
    if any(distances <= distance_threshold):
        filtered_rows.append(row2)

filtered_df2 = pd.DataFrame(filtered_rows)

print(filtered_df2)
```

Would be happy about any approch which might help

Comment: Can you share code for a minimum reproducible example?